# Xcode Crash Log - Call Stack replaced with C Function name

Tags: ios, c, objective-c, xcode, crash-log

I have a crash in some code from an `XCFramework` binary that I have embedded in my app.
When I symobilicate the the code, the name of the methods in the call stack of the crash are replaced with the name of a C function in an objective-C class.
e.g.

```
7  <redacted>                       0x335988 <redacted>_PINRemoteImageManagerSubclassOverridesSelector + 1729336
```

For different crashes it seems to pick a random C Function from the code and uses it for the name of the method in the call stack.

I have no idea why this would be happening.
Any thoughts or suggestions would be welcome.
Thanks

```
    Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0xa01c __pthread_kill + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x5680 pthread_kill + 268
2  libsystem_c.dylib              0x75b90 abort + 180
3  libswiftCore.dylib             0x3a24d8 swift::fatalError(unsigned int, char const*, ...) + 126
4  libswiftCore.dylib             0x3a24f8 swift::warningv(unsigned int, char const*, char*) + 30
5  libswiftCore.dylib             0x3a26b4 swift::swift_abortRetainUnowned(void const*) + 32
6  libswiftCore.dylib             0x3ff018 swift_unknownObjectUnownedTakeStrong + 74
7  <redacted>                       0x335988 <redacted>_PINRemoteImageManagerSubclassOverridesSelector + 1729336
8  <redacted>                       0x280f40 <redacted>_PINRemoteImageManagerSubclassOverridesSelector + 989424
9  <redacted>                       0x298024 <redacted>_PINRemoteImageManagerSubclassOverridesSelector + 1083860
10 <redacted>                       0x297b68 <redacted>_PINRemoteImageManagerSubclassOverridesSelector + 1082648
11 libdispatch.dylib              0x26a8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
12 libdispatch.dylib              0x4300 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
13 libdispatch.dylib              0x12998 _dispatch_main_queue_drain + 984
14 libdispatch.dylib              0x125b0 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 44
15 CoreFoundation                 0x3720c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 16
16 CoreFoundation                 0x33f18 __CFRunLoopRun + 1996
17 CoreFoundation                 0x33668 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 608
18 GraphicsServices               0x35ec GSEventRunModal + 164
19 UIKitCore                      0x22c2b4 -[UIApplication _run] + 888
20 UIKitCore                      0x22b8f0 UIApplicationMain + 340
```

Comment: Is this within your debugger, or on a release build? A debugger should be able to drop you into the actual call-site, regardless of whatever is being reported here.

Comment: This is on a release build

Comment: Download DSYMs from appstoreconnect.apple.com

Comment: Just to clarify, this crash log has been deSymbolicated.

Comment: But with wrong DSYMs

Comment: There is something wrong with the symbols.  It's finding the nearest one, that random function, but then the offset numbers are huge so that symbol is nowhere near the crash.  It doesn't have names for any symbols closer than that.